# HTML: I want to create a DIV thats horizontal centered and reaches from the top to the bottom

Tags: css, html

I want to create a page with a horizontal centered content block that reaches from teh top to the bottom of the browser window. I already figured out that tables are not the right way to design a layout. A block that reaches from top to bottom is not the problem:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;width:800px;height:100%;background-color: #fff;">
</div>
```

But I'm not able to make this Div centered. I tried

"margin:auto"

But no effect. Th centers the text in the Div, but not the Div itself on th screen.

Comment: Word of warning to ye, my friends, heed the answer with automatic margins, for you see, absolute positioning is a slippery slope, and before you know it, you'll be running over kindergarteners with a pickup truck held together by duct tape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use `position:absolute` for layouts unless necessary. [This sample](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html) shows best practice for horizontally centering your content.

If you need a solution that will continuously work to restrain the content area height within the viewable area, try my jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/Z75hA/

Answer (score 2):

To center a div you need two things, a width, and automatic horizontal margins.  Like this:

```
#myDiv {
    width:800px; /* or whatever */
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

There is no need for absolute positioning, just these two rules will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

to center an Absolutely Positioned div add `left: 50%; margin-left: -400px;`

where the **negative** margin value is half the width of the div

Comment: Good answer, but try to avoid using positon:absolute unless you are forced to use it. I believe your height of 100% won't work in all browsers if you use absolute positioning.